# Enable Always on Top For Caliburn Managed Window

Tags: caliburn.micro

I have the following ViewModel and I am using Caliburn Micro. The IWindowManager instance is properly resolved and all of the code works. As indicated by the TODO comment, I need to get a reference to the current window so I can toggle the AlwaysOnTop attribute. How can I do that?

```
namespace CaliburnWizardPlay
{
[Export(typeof(DropWindowViewModel))]
public class DropWindowViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IHaveDisplayName
{
    private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public DropWindowViewModel(IWindowManager windowManager)
    {
        this.windowManager = windowManager;
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get { return "Main Window"; }
        set { }
    }        

    public bool AlwaysOnTop
    {
        get { return Settings.Default.DropWindowAlwaysOnTop; }
        set
        {
            Settings.Default.DropWindowAlwaysOnTop = value;
            Settings.Default.Save();
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => AlwaysOnTop);
            //todo: toggle the AOT attribute of the window
        }
    }

    public void FileDropped(DragEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] droppedFilePaths = eventArgs.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
            foreach (string path in droppedFilePaths)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(path);
            }

            windowManager.ShowWindow(new WizardViewModel());
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is my question unclear or does nobody know a way to set the attribute?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `settings` parameter of the `ShowWindow` method to set any property (e.g. [Topmost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost.aspx)) on the created window with a dictionary containing propertyname-value pairs:

```cs
windowManager.ShowWindow(new WizardViewModel(), 
    settings: new Dictionary<string,object> { {"Topmost", AlwaysOnTop} });
```

If you want to change the `Topmost` property of the already created window I see three options (in the order of preference):

1. Create an `AlwaysOnTop` property on the `WizardViewModel` and store the viewmodel in a private field and delegate the `AlwaysOnTop` to the `WizardViewModel`:

   ```cs
   private WizardViewModel wizardViewModel;

   public void FileDropped(DragEventArgs eventArgs)
   {
       //...
       wizardViewModel = new WizardViewModel()
       windowManager.ShowWindow(wizardViewModel);
   }

   public bool AlwaysOnTop
   {
        get { return Settings.Default.DropWindowAlwaysOnTop; }
        set
        {
            //...
            if (wizardViewModel != null)
                wizardViewModel.AlwaysOnTop = value;
        }
   }
   ```

   And in your view you can bind the `WizardViewModel`'s `AlwaysOnTop` property to the window's `TopMost` property.
2. You can use the [Application.Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) to retrieve the window. E.g. set the `Name` property of the created Window with the settings dictionary and then:

   ```cs
   windowManager.ShowWindow(new WizardViewModel(), 
       settings: new Dictionary<string,object> 
           { {"Topmost", AlwaysOnTop}, {"Name", "WizardWindow"} });

   public bool AlwaysOnTop
   {
        get { return Settings.Default.DropWindowAlwaysOnTop; }
        set
        {
            //...
            var wizardViewModel = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>()
                .SingleOrDefault(w => w.Name == "WizardWindow");
            if (wizardViewModel != null)
                wizardViewModel.AlwaysOnTop = value;
        }
   }
   ```
3. Derive from the `WindowManager` and register it in your `Bootstrapper` and then you can override the `CreateWindow`, `EnsureWindow` etc. methods to store the created windows somewhere set the additional properties etc.

Comment: @michaelkoss with the current Caliburn API you can't get a reference of the created window it's not that simple, see my updated answer.

Comment: Getting closer, but I need to set the Topmost on the window that has the AlwaysOnTop property, not the newly created WizardViewModel--the DropWindowViewModel in my example code. But I think your solution #3 will work for that too because (I believe) Caliburn would use my IWindowManager to open the very first window of the app.